# LRC and CRC calculation in nmodbus library

Tags: c#, modbus

I used nmodbus library in one of the application. I know this question is silly, but in ModbusMaster using nmodbus does it take care `LRC` and `CRC` in modbus ASCII and RTU respectively? Or do we have to do it separately?

For example when we use this nmodbus function 
`master1.WriteSingleRegister(slaveId, startAdd, WrValue);` it takes only 3 arguments slaveId StartAdd and value to write. So when it send the data packet to the port will it take care of the CRC or LRC as per the protocol?

Also If I want to see the datapacket for Tx and Rx of the port in the same application can see it? I mean is it possible to see the Raw received and transmit data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for sure that NModbus will generate a `CRC` for `Modbus RTU`.

You can read any incoming data to your serial port with the  [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application) is another tutorial.

Comment: SerialPort.DataReceived event is not showing anything. is there another way to see the port activity?

Comment: @SPandya I understand that the topic is already old, but for me it is still relevant. Maybe you know - is it possible to get CRC from nmodbus lib?